# How to mock with NSubstitute a method with an array parameter?

Tags: mocking, nsubstitute

I have the following interface:

```
interface IText
{
    void CopyTo(char[] array, int index);
}
```

I would like to create a mock object implementing `IText` which sets`array[index]='f'`, `array[index+1]='o'`, `array[index+2]='o'` when `CopyTo` is called.

Is this possible with NSubstitute? If so, how?

Comment: Note: `IText` must be public to be substituted using NSubstitute and other Dynamic Proxy-based mocking libraries.

Comment: @DavidTchepak: Or use [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("DynamicProxyGenAssembly2")]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mandatory disclaimer: this is generally not advisable. We normally use an interface like `IText` because we don't want the code to depend on implementation details like this, just on the contract. Implementing specific behaviour in a substitute means our code under test is tightly coupled to a specific implementation of this interface. Instead, try using `textSub.Received().CopyTo(...)` to check the contract was used correctly by the calling code.

Now that's out of the way, we can use `When..Do` to set up this behaviour:

```
var text = Substitute.For<IText>();
text.WhenForAnyArgs(x => x.CopyTo(null, 0))
    .Do(x => {
          var index = x.Arg<int>();
          var array = x.Arg<char[]>();
          array[index] = 'f';
          array[index+1] = 'o';
          // etc...
    });
```